# 404 page not found error after joomla website migration

Tags: joomla, configuration, server

I have been transfer all file from old server to the new server.
Also the old server database to new server database. This new server for example http://server.com/newserver same like http://oldserver.com. But the main menu or article show 404 not found. Below are my configuration.php

```
public $log_path = '/home/public_html/newserver/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/home/public_html/newserver/tmp';
public $user = 'new_user';
public $password = '812tq3iurhb';
public $db = 'new_db';
public $dbprefix = 'ybqsn_';
public $live_site = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem solve after go to global setting and disable SEO url and rewritting

Answer (score 0):

Hello it seems to be a htaccess problem, check if the .htaccess have been copied to the new server or check with your hosting provider the correct RewriteBase configuration

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue but i resolved this by modifying .htaccess file and enabled **RewriteBase /**